# The taxonomy term field token doesn't show in Views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to call my taxonomy field token in the Views header.

- I added the relationship "Content: Taxonomy terms on node," and then added the taxonomy term in the fields;
- I went to the header settings and added the global text area, inside of which I checked "Replace with tokens";
- I added my token.

This is my view and I am pretty sure this is a bug or I am doing something completely wrong.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean with "I added my token"? Did you implement a token in a module you created? Did you verify the token you are using is listed between the available tokens?

Comment: yeah the token is listed under replacement tokens but when you preview the block it doesnt output anything, i tried using other tokens that wasnt a taxonomy term field but they work fine, only my taxonomy term field token doesnt work

Comment: Did you check the token has been correctly implemented?

Comment: yes i think my problem is that the content of the relationship isnt being called 1st heres a screen shot of what its doing im not sure how i can make the relationship content show 1st insted of the contexual filter content thats showing 1st, if you can give me your input on how i can fix this i think that would solve my problem

http://i.imgur.com/scOci.jpg

http://i.imgur.com/cuA0K.jpg

http://i.imgur.com/siPZP.jpg